# Is a loop more efficient than regex in a lexer?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreter, lexer

I am writing a toy language for curiosity's sake. I have written a functioning lexer to create tokens using a number of regular expressions.

From a performance point of view, is it faster/more efficient to loop through the source code character by character and figure out the tokens or should I stick with regex? Just curious how "proper" lexers are implemented.

Comment: It really depends on how you implement it. Badly written loop will likely be slower than regex, while carefully optimized one will likely be faster. For a toy language, I would start with what's easier for you and then try other approaches if the performance is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the architecture of the computers we use, a regex ends up being implemented with loops.

If the code is structured, it will be a combination of something like a `switch` statement within a `while` statement, with the cases in the `switch` representing the states of the [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that recognizes the same language as the regex.

If ***goto*** is allowed, the implementation can be much more efficient than what a generic regex library can do.

Unless you have specific efficiency needs, sticking to a regex library should be efficient enough, and it will save you lots of programming (debugging) time.

Comment: I wrote [Grako](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grako) and I boldly went for the underlying `re` module in Python's standard library.